# Using threading.Lock as context manager

Tags: python, multithreading, contextmanager

In the documentation of the [threading](https://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement) module it says:

> All of the objects provided by this module that have `acquire()` and `release()` methods can be used as context managers for a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) statement. The `acquire()` method will be called when the block is entered, and `release()` will be called when the block is exited.

I was wondering if it is called in blocking or non-blocking mode?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From looking at the [CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d8ca2354ed30c12b9ce37c4535222b700a727b32/Lib/threading.py#L95), it appears that it's called with default arguments, which means in blocking mode.

The methods you want to look at in particular are [`__enter__()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d8ca2354ed30c12b9ce37c4535222b700a727b32/Lib/threading.py#L161), which is called at the beginning of the `with` block, and [`__exit__()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d8ca2354ed30c12b9ce37c4535222b700a727b32/Lib/threading.py#L186-L187), which is called at the end.