# Multithreading synchronization using Lock Object

Tags: python, multithreading

I have been searching for some explanations about thread synchronization. I have found a challenge to use as case of study, I will simply here with my solution. Basically there is a class with a numeric value, and you can add or subtract from it. If there is many threads accessing this instance, it should wait all threads finishes before return the final value. My implementation is the following:

```
from threading import Lock, Thread
from time import sleep
import sys

class ClassA(object):

   def with_lock():
        def wrapper(func):
            def wrapped(self, *args):
                with self.lock:
                    return func(self, *args)
            return wrapped
        return wrapper

   def __init__(self, balance = 0):
      self.balance = balance
      self.lock = Lock()

   def get_balance(self):
      return self.balance

   @with_lock()
   def add(self):
      self.balance += 1

   @with_lock()
   def sub(self):
      self.balance -= 1


if __name__ == "__main__":

   sys.setswitchinterval(1e-12)

   value = 10

   def foo():
      a.add()
      sleep(0.01)
      a.sub()

   a = ClassA(value)

   threads = [Thread(target=foo) for _ in range(1000)]
   for thread in threads:
      thread.start()
   for thread in threads:
      thread.join()

   print(a.get_balance()) # should return "value"
```

The implementation of the decorator "with_lock" was found in other implementation from the internet, but I did not understand it.

About this part:

```
with self.lock:
    return func(self, *args)
```

I have searched about the Lock documentation, and it shows that self.lock would be a Lock Object with methods acquire and release. Can I understand the 'with' statement would wait until the thread is released? Or is there any other behavior?

The print at the end waits until all the threads to finish, but the get_balance does not have the decorator "with_lock". Why it waits until the threads finish?

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/q/13290429/1358308 help with `Lock`s being context managers?  calling `thread.join()` will wait for the thread to finish…  also, reading/returning the balance reference is (thanks to the GIL) atomic, hence no need for a lock

Comment: Hello, that helps. About the balance getter, I still did not understand it. Because if I do not have that function running in the decorator, it return "random" values inside the range possible,it runs the join method for all the threads, but goes to the print before all is done.

Comment: why do you say it "goes to the print before all is done"?  [`thread.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) is defined to "Wait until the thread terminates".  try putting a `print` at the end of `foo`, all the `foo`s should have returned before `get_balance` is evaluated

Comment: This code is a representation of a test case, it should return at the end the value after all the threads finished.